# jQuery code is not showing the form second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form when I click registration button the form animates and also the close button becomes visible then I click close button the form hides and the registration button becomes visible again, but the problem is when I again click registration button the form doesn't appears again but the close button does.

And also short format jQuery code for this purpose is also appreciable if anyone suggest.

I added my code fiddle below

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#close').hide();

      $('#regbtn').click(function () {
           $('#close').show();
           $('#regbtn').hide(1000);

           $('#firstCont').animate({
                position:'absolute',
                right: '40px',
                top: '20%',
                opacity: '1',
                height: '800px',
                width: '800px',
                margin: '0 50px 0 100px'
           });
      });
      $('#close').click(function(){
           $('#firstCont').hide(1000);
           $('#close').hide(1000);
           $('#regbtn').show(1000);
      });
 });


</script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('#close').hide();

      $('#regbtn').click(function () {
           $('#close').show();
           $('#regbtn').hide(1000);

           $('#firstCont').animate({
                position:'absolute',
                right: '40px',
                top: '20%',
                opacity: '1',
                height: '800px',
                width: '800px',
                margin: '0 50px 0 100px'
           });
      });
      $('#close').click(function(){
           $('#firstCont').hide(1000);
           $('#close').hide(1000);
           $('#regbtn').show(1000);
      });
 });
```

```css
.col-centered {
 border:3px solid blue;
}
#primary {
 padding:15px;
}
#firstCont {
 height:0px;
 width:0px;
 overflow:hidden;
 opacity:0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" >
 <div class="row">
  <div class="text-center"> 
   <button class="btn btn-success btn" id="regbtn">Click For Regestration</button>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="text-center"> 
   <button class="btn btn-danger" id="close">Close</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="container" >
 <div class="row">
  <div class="text-center" > 

  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid" id="firstCont">
 <div class="row centered-form center-block">

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-centered">
   <form id="primary">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="name">Name:</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" required id="email" placeholder="Enter Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="email">Email:</label>
     <input type="email" class="form-control" required id="pwd" placeholder="Enter Email">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" required>
     <label for="gender">Gender:</label>
     <select class="form-control" id="gender">
      <option>--Select Gender--</option>
      <option>Male</option>
      <option>Female</option>
     </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" required id="phone" placeholder="Enter Phone">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="add">Address:</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" required id="address" placeholder="Enter Address">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="country">Country:</label>
     <select class="form-control" id="country">
      <option>--Select Country--</option>
      <option>Bangladesh</option>
      <option>Chaina</option>
      <option>Germany</option>
      <option>India</option>
     </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" required>
     <label for="city">City:</label>
     <select class="form-control" id="city">
      <option>--Select City--</option>
     </select>
    </div>

    <div class="text-right"> 
     <button class="btn-info btn" id="submit">SUBMIT</button>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

[ProblemFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/25576/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/25570/). Instead of `hide()` I've used `animate({...})` to set the base style of the form.

Basically, when you hide your form, you should set it's style to the same as base one.
Or, if you want to use `hide()`, you have to use `show()` instead of `animate({...})`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
$('#regbtn').click(function() {
    $('#close').show();
    $('#regbtn').hide(1000);
    $('#firstCont').show(1000);
    $('#firstCont').animate({
        position: 'absolute',
        right: '20px',
        top: '20%',
        opacity: '1',
        height: '700px',
        width: '700px',
        margin: '0 50px 0 100px'
    });
});
```

[working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/25573/)

Answer (score 2):

You are hiding #firstcount and not showing it again. Try this modification:

```
$('#regbtn').click(function(){
$('#close').show();
$('#regbtn').hide(1000);
$('#firstCont').show(1000); // here
$('#firstCont').animate({
    position:'absolute',
    right: '20px',
    top: '20%',
    opacity: '1',
    height: '700px',
    width: '700px',
      margin: '0 50px 0 100px'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `hide()` on `#firstCont`. So when you want to display it again, you need to call `show()`.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to resolve it would be to set values of css element that needs to be animated first, because hide sets display value to none, which needs to be put back to "block", as it were in your case.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#close').hide();

      $('#regbtn').click(function () {
           $('#close').show();
           $('#regbtn').hide(1000);

           $('#firstCont').css("display","block");
           $('#firstCont').css("height","0");
           $('#firstCont').css("width","0");

           $('#firstCont').animate({
                position:'absolute',
                right: '40px',
                top: '20%',
                opacity: '1',
                height: '800px',
                width: '800px',
                margin: '0 50px 0 100px'
           });
      });
      $('#close').click(function(){
           $('#firstCont').hide(1000);
           $('#close').hide(1000);
           $('#regbtn').show(1000);
      });
 });


</script>
```

You can test it here: https://jsfiddle.net/acosonic/4k3ntfmg/1/